# Why won't curl download this image?

Tags: curl, terminal, zsh

I'm trying to download the image located at this URL https://www.augsburger-allgemeine.de/img/panorama/crop61911941/0409422329-cv16_9-w940-owebp/Wassermassen-in-Australien?t=.jpg with `curl`, i.e:

```
curl -O https://www.augsburger-allgemeine.de/img/panorama/crop61911941/0409422329-cv16_9-w940-owebp/Wassermassen-in-Australien?t=.jpg
```

But I just get:

```
zsh: no matches found: https://www.augsburger-allgemeine.de/img/panorama/crop61911941/0409422329-cv16_9-w940-owebp/Wassermassen-in-Australien?t=.jpg
```

Can anyone explain to me why this is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Analysis

In terms of `zsh` the question mark (`?`) is a wildcard character.

Let's refer to the documentation.

[zsh: 14 Expansion: 14.8 Filename Generation](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Filename-Generation):

> ### 14.8 Filename Generation
>
> If a word contains an unquoted instance of one of the characters ‘ *’, ‘(’, ‘|’, ‘<’, ‘[’, or ‘?’, it is regarded as a pattern for filename generation, unless the GLOB option is unset. If the EXTENDED_GLOB option is set, the ‘^’ and ‘#’ characters also denote a pattern; otherwise they are not treated specially by the shell.
>
> <…>

Please, note:

> If a word contains an unquoted instance

[zsh: 14 Expansion: 14.8.1 Glob Operators](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Operators):

> #### 14.8.1 Glob Operators
>
> <…>
>
> `?` Matches any character.
>
> <…>

## Possible solution

Surround each argument containing wildcard characters with quotes (single quotes or double quotes), so that the argument is not regarded as a pattern for file name generation.

For example:

```
curl -O 'https://www.augsburger-allgemeine.de/img/panorama/crop61911941/0409422329-cv16_9-w940-owebp/Wassermassen-in-Australien?t=.jpg'
```